# Regex: Obtain ID(s) from URL

Tags: regex, parsing, url

Getting my feet wet in Regular Expressions, and I'm having a difficult time getting this one to work.

I have a url as such:

/800-Flowers-inc-**4124**/18-roses-**3123**

Where 4124 is the business ID, and 3123 is the product ID.

The hard part for me is creating the capturing groups. Currently, my regex is as follows:

```
/(\d+)(?=/|$)/g
```

Unfortunately, that only selects the business ID, and doesn't return the product ID.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and if you provide a regex, I would love if you could put a little explanation

thanks!

Comment: What flavour of regex are you using? php? .net? javascript? something else?

Comment: Hey guys, it's javascript (node.js)

Comment: @Nouman: Works fine for me after escaping, which I assume you've done already (otherwise, it wouldn't have matched anything): `'/800-Flowers-inc-4124/18-roses-3123'.match(/(\d+)(?=\/|$)/g)`

Comment: Are you using `exec()` to get the results?

Comment: No, I'm actually just console.log()ing an array (req.params) which should contain all the url matches. The framework I'm using is expressjs (http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing) which from the examples, shows regex working to obtain url information, somehow mine still returns an array with only the first item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is fine, except since you've used the `/` as the regex delimiter you need to escape it in the expression:

```
/(\d+)(?=\/|$)/g
```

Or, you can just use a different delimiter (e.g. @):

```
@(\d+)(?=/|$)@g
```

Depending on the language you're using it'll probably return the results in some sort of array, or there could be a 'findAll'-type method instead of just 'find'.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; however, it doesn't seem to include both. I'm using node.js with express, and when I visit that url and output req.params (which is an array of matches) I only receive the first `app.get(/(\d+)(?=\/|$)/g, products.show);` some info on that here: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try this question over on an expressjs board to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

mathematical.coffee is correct:

```
 var data = '/800-Flowers-inc-4124/18-roses-3123';
        var myregexp = /(\d+)(?=\/|$)/g;
        var match = myregexp.exec(data);
        var result = "Matches:\n";
        while (match != null) {
            result += "match:" + match[0] + ',\n';
            match = myregexp.exec(data);
        }
        alert(result);
```